# SQL Server : how to get the newest date in a table with several equal keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having, accounting

Unfortunately my knowledge related to statements like `group by` and `having` is quite limited, so hopefully you can help me:

I have a view - here's an excerpt - (if we have some Europeans here - it's v021 of Winline/Mesonic):

```
ID        | Artikelbezeichnung1                 | Bez2      | mesoyear
_____________________________________________________________________
1401MA70  | Marga ,Saracena grigio,1S,33,3/33,3 | Marazzi   | 1344
1401MA70  | Marga ,Saracena grigio,1S,33,3/33,3 | Marazzi   | 1356
1401MA70  | Marga ,Saracena grigio,1S,33,3/33,3 | Marazzi   | 1356
1401MA71  | Marga ,Saracena beige,1S,33,3/33,3  | Marazzi   | 1344
1401MA71  | Marga ,Saracena beige,1S,33,3/33,3  | Marazzi   | 1356
1401MA71  | Marga ,Saracena beige,1S,33,3/33,3  | Marazzi   | 1356    
2401CR13  | Crista,Mahon rojo,1S,33,3/33,3      | Cristacer | 1332    
2401CR13  | Crista,Mahon rojo,1S,33,3/33,3      | Cristacer | 1344
```

So the `ID` is not unique and I just need the one with the highest val in `mesoyear`.

My fist solution was:

```
Select 
    c015 as ID,
    c003 as Artikelbezeichnung1,
    c074 as Bez2,
    mesoyear
from 
    CWLDATEN_91.dbo.v021
group by 
    c015
having 
    mesoyear = max(mesoyear)
```

But this doesn't work at all...

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Column 'CWLDATEN_91.dbo.v021.mesoyear' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I just removed the `having` statement and it went "better":

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'CWLDATEN_91.dbo.v021.c003' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I tried to remove the error just by adding things to the "group by". And it worked.

```
Select 
    c015 as ID,
    c003 as Artikelbezeichnung1,
    c074 as Bez2,
    max(mesoyear)
from 
    CWLDATEN_91.dbo.v021
group by 
    c015, c003, c074
```

gives me exactly what I want.

But the correct select contains about 24 columns and some calculations as well. The problem can't be solved just by adding all the columns to the `group by`...?

Can someone please help me to find a proper command?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you already got the answers using `ROW_NUMBER`, I am just going to add you a few links about T-SQL's ranking functions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx &  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: And also if you just want to use `GROUP BY` - it's possible. You can wrap you grouping result in sub-query then `JOIN` it back to original table using all grouping columns. (but I'd recommend row_number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually want `group by`.  You want to select the last line in each group.  You can do this with the window function called `row_number()` (assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or greater):

```
Select v.*
from (select v.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c015, c003, c074 order by mesoyear desc) as seqnum
      from CWLDATEN_91.dbo.v021
     ) v
where seqnum = 1;
```

`Row_number()` assigns a sequential number to rows in a group.  So, all rows with the same value for `c015`, `c003`, and `c074` (based on the `partition by` clause) are in a group and are numbered.  The orders is by the most recent `mesoyear` first (based on the `order by` clause).  So, the value of `1` in `seqnum` is the most recent year.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with `ROW_NUMBER()` assuming SQL Server 2005 or later

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c015, c003, c074 ORDER BY mesoyear DESC) RowRank
      FROM CWLDATEN_91.dbo.v021)sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function just numbers rows in whatever fashion you dictate, here it's a grouped by your key fields, and ordered by `mesoyear`.